# Trying to make a simple JQuery/JavaScript calculation

Tags: javascript, calculation

I'm pretty fresh regarding JS/JQuery, and I'm trying to make a simple calculation/function based on a code I found earlier here. The original code works great, it sums a given col and appends the result as in a new row. 
I'm now trying to get a percentage of said result.

```
<script>

var result = [];
$('#table tr').each(function(){
$('td#pay', this).each(function(index, val){
    if(!result[index]) result[index] = 0;
  result[index] += parseInt($(val).text());
});
});

var varTax = 24;



$('#table').append('<tr></tr>');
$(result).each(function(){
$('#table tr').last().append('<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td><td><b>Totalt</b></td><td id="sumOfPay">'+this+' kr</td><td colspan="2">'+( 100 - varTax ) / 100 * this+'</td>')

});

</script>
```

`var taxCalc` and `var taxTot` is what I've added. But this only prints [object Object].

**Edit: I figured it out. The formula I was looking for was `+( 100 - varTax ) / 100 * this+`**

Comment: Please add full code along with your HTML

Comment: Without HTML your code is meaningless.

Comment: You are getting down voted because it's really hard to guess what the rest of your code looks like. Most likely, you need to do `this.value` instead, but without knowing what your HTML looks like, no one can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula I was looking for was `+( 100 - varTax ) / 100 * this+`